# why do some java objects can't get value references

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Java pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

when I used some java class like (Integer, File, Boolean)
if I pass the instance as an argument to a function and try to change its value 
after I use this value outside function, the value remains unchanged.

for example:

```
private void run(){
        File tmpFile;
        setFile(tmpFile);
        System.out.println(tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());  //error tmpFile is null
    }

private void setFile(File xFile){
    xFile = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();  // this returned object file
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that Java uses call-by-value, not call-by-reference.

In your `setFile` method, your assignment to `xFile` only changes the local variable.  It does not change the variable `tmpFile` in the `run()` method.

You should write the code so that `setFile` returns a value; e.g.

```
    private void run(){
        File tmpFile = getFile();
        System.out.println(tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    private File getFile() {
        return jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    }
```

(Note: I changed the method name, because a method called `setXXX` that doesn't actually set anything is gratuitously misleading.)

Answer (score 0):

Java always passes by value. You shouldn't expect any other behaviour.

A method can only change an object when you pass a reference (The reference is still passed by value)